# Why "pointer=pointer+i" got kind of random value

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some code to read "db_data" (type is std::vector) from database, and to interpret it as array of ipsecSeqTable_t.
some code piece like below:

```
typedef struct ipsecSeqTable
{
    uint64_t seq;
    uint64_t oseq;
    uint32_t spi;
} ipsecSeqTable_t;

ipsecSeqTable_t* seq_data = reinterpret_cast<ipsecSeqTable_t*>(&db_data[0]);
        uint32_t seq_data_count = db_data.size()/sizeof(ipsecSeqTable_t);

        for (uint32_t i=0; i<seq_data_count; i++)
        {
            seq_data = seq_data + i;
            printf("seq_data addr %ld", reinterpret_cast<int64_t>(seq_data ))
            ....
```

This code doesn't work(db_data incorrectly interpreted). With some logging I　found problem is in "seq_data = seq_data + i", I got this print:

```
seq_data addr 140737018602320
seq_data addr 140737018602344
seq_data addr 140737018602392
seq_data addr 140737018602464
```

sieof(ipsecSeqTable_t) is 24, so I expect the address adds 24*i, so
the 3rd seq_data addr should be 140737018602368, the 4th should be 140737018602392

If I change seq_data = seq_data + i to below:

```
ipsecSeqTable_t* temp_seq_data = seq_data + i;
```

I got correct interpretion, and print temp_seq_data gets:

```
temp_seq_data addr 140737018602320
temp_seq_data addr 140737018602344
temp_seq_data addr 140737018602368
temp_seq_data addr 140737018602492
```

Can some explain why "seq_data = seq_data + i" is wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably shouldn't print the pointer as a signed type.

Comment: You're adding 1, 2, 3, 4, ... to the pointer, so the position goes like 1, 3, 6, 10, ...

Comment: ... and soon greatly exceeds the size of the array.

Comment: You should add 1 instead of i

Comment: Please don't use `reinterpret_cast` for type punning. Use `memcpy` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq_data = seq_data + i;` is the same as `seq_data += i;` -- i.e., seq_data is moved to the right `i` times.

I believe you're trying to move seq_data to '`i` spaces to the right of its original location', which is what your code with the temporary variable is doing, since it refers to the original location each time. Alternatively, you could just move seq_data to the right once each iteration, which is this:

```
for (uint32_t i=0; i<seq_data_count; i++) {
    seq_data = seq_data + 1; // or seq_data += 1; or ++seq_data;
    printf("seq_data addr %ld", reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(seq_data ))
    ....
}
```